# How can I solve characters error twitter?

Tags: php, twitter, special-characters

I am developing one twitter applications.

I have one problem ;

I want to post a message to twitter If i use turkish or some characters , it doesn't post.

My code :

```
 $mesajing  = "Dear @".$username." : You have ".$ozelmsjs." messages you can read the messages ->".$url."";
 $status    = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status'=>$mesajing));
 $status->response;
```

Comment: What is the encoding used in the the `$username` and `$ozelmsj` variable? Which encoding does `$twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate` accept?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$encoded = utf8_encode($mesajing);
$status    = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status'=>$encoded));
```

Or try doing:

```
$encoded = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $mesajing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper encoding, Twitter is **probably** (read the documentation to be sure) using UTF8.

Comment: but i use utf8 . This is the same result.

Comment: what do you mean by 'i use utf-8'? is your php document in utf-8?
do you set encoding headers?

Comment: Yeah, using UTF8 to encode your PHP doesn't mean the pages and your database are using UTF8. A quick test would be to use `utf8_encode` before sending your message. If it works, you're probably using ISO8859-1 in your app and you must `utf8_encode` your message before sending it.

Comment: Then `dump` your message before sending it and see what you are actually trying to send. Do you have any error given by the API ?

Comment: I dont have any error by API . For example my message is Özel Mesajiniz mevcuttur

with utf8_encode() -> ÃƒÂ–zel Mesajiniz mevcuttur. And it didn't post.